# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_kses_normalize_entities() in new wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, installation

I'm trying to install Wordpress 5.3.2 on NetBSD (unix). phpinfo() tells me I am running Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) PHP/7.2.6

On install.php I get a blank screen and the server log says 
Call to undefined function wp_kses_normalize_entities()

As this is at the installation stage, I've not got as far as a Wordpress dashboard, so there are no plugins to disable. What do I do?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-wp_kses_normalize_entities/

Comment: Alas that doesn't help. It seems to say the problem is a result of trying to view the site before it is installed. So I downloaded again and wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1 is still giving the "There has been a critical error on your website." message and in the server log says "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function json_encode()" and points to /wp-includes/functions.php:3820

Comment: It sounds like a flaw in whatever installation routine you're running relative to the server environment, but I don't know enough about either - or what you're actually doing - to say. You might do better with what whatever tech support or community support you can access than on a board like this one, but I can't say for sure!